# Find the volume given a vector field and the flux

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

The problem gives that $$
\int_{E} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} d S=1
$$
where$$
\mathbf{F}=\left(3 x,\left(x^{2}+z^{2}\right) y^{2},\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) z^{2}\right)
$$
and asks to find the volume enclosed by $E$. My first attempt is to use the divergence theorem, but the divergence here does not reduce to a constant or something simple. I also think the squares are suggesting the usage of spherical coordinates maybe, but I do not see how. Any hints or solutions are appreciated!

Comment: same question asked today by another user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4361269/find-volume-of-surface-given-iint-e-mathbff-cdot-mathbfn-ds-1

Comment: @ Math Lover The post was deleted. Did it have an answer?

Comment: No. I asked where the problem came from, as I don't see enough information to begin to solve it as it stands. So I'll ask you. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: If you find the divergence of the vector field, you will notice that there is a constant term and other terms are odd functions of $y$ and $z$. So the intent may have been of $E$ symmetric to y and z planes but there is not enough information in the question to take that route.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin This is a question from a past qualifying exam at my school. It is possible that the original question had a typo which they did not correct on the resources, but based on the average difficulty of the exam, I don’t think the divergence of F should reduce to a constant or anything particularly simple here